# How to plot only a specific DBSCAN label using matplotlib?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, label, dbscan

I'm working with sckitlearn/matplotlib to clusterize and plot some data, with 3D projection. The code is working fine, but now I want to plot only a specific DBSCAN label.

I expect to plot individually the labels 0 or 1 or 2, so I can identify more easily the data in each cluster. How can I extract these values? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array indexing.

You *can* plot `X[label == 1]` easily.

Comment: I'm plotting like:

    plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], X[:,2], c=db.labels_, cmap='rainbow')

Altering to:

    plt.scatter(X[db.labels_ == 1], c=db.labels_, cmap='rainbow')

or

    plt.scatter(X[db.labels_ == 1], X[db.labels_ == 1], X[db.labels_ == 1], c=db.labels_, cmap='rainbow')

did not go well.

Comment: Since `X` is 2d, you'll want a two dimensional index there, as before. Or you define `subX=X[labels==1]` and plot it as before.